# Is it possible to use javascript to build sequential code

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use javascript to build code that interacts with a database and then uses the information to send the viewer to the next sequential step?

Comment: JS shouldnt directly interact with DB. If you have the backend (PHP/ASP/...) fetching info from your DB, JS can do the navigation part.

Comment: @Cthulhu, I see no reasons why JavaScript (server side) should not interact with DB. I'd be surprised if one prefer some other language to access DB when using node.js.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I meant client-side JS. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have some kind of server side scripting to query the database. You can then use AJAX from javascript to call those server side scripts which will perform the database functions and return the result back to javascript which can then move the page to the next step.

You will not be able to connect directly to a database using javascript.